Contemporary Western film about father and son(s) who witness a stagecoach robbery
American movie.  Released in the last 10 or so years.  All I remember is one scene:
Father and son (possibly sons) are up on a rocky/dirt slope.  They witness a stagecoach robbery.  Much gunfire.  The bad guys eventually kill everyone on the stagecoach, and I believe the payload was a safe.  The stagecoach may have been bank-owned but I'm not positive.  I want to say after the robbery, the leader of the bad guys shoots one of his own men for some reason.  
The aforementioned father and son(s) decide not to get involved at all.  The bad guys may have seen them after the robbery, I can't remember.
I'm sorry, that's all I have to go on.  I remember seeing it on HBO, it wasn't a b-movie or anything, it was a pretty mainstream Hollywood movie.

I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

I'll leave it, but the film isn't really about them witnessing the robbery.  That's just one small piece of it.

That sounds like "3:10 to Yuma" (the 2007 remake): 

Rancher Dan Evans heads into Bisbee to clear up issues concerning the sale of his land when he witnesses the closing events of a stagecoach robbery led by famed outlaw Ben Wade. Shortly thereafter, Wade is captured by the law in Bisbee and Evans finds himself one of the escorts who will take Wade to the 3:10 to Yuma train in Contention for the reward of $200. Evans's effort to take Wade to the station is in part an effort to save his land but also part of an inner battle to determine whether he can be more than just a naive rancher in the eyes of his impetuous and gunslinging son William Evans. The transport to Contention is hazardous and filled with ambushes by Indians, pursuits by Wade's vengeful gang and Wade's own conniving and surreptitious demeanor that makes the ride all the more intense.

This fits your time frame of your film, as well as the scenes: Pretty early on in the movie The main character (Christian Bale) and his two sons witness the stagecoach robbery, but don't get involved. The bad guys (lead by Russell Crowe), do notice that Christian Bale and his sons see the robbery, but acknowledge that they pose no threat and ride off.

What I had in mind as well.

This is exactly it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAaTV-pwYBA  Thanks!
